# Monte Carlo Standard Deviation Equation

Tags: java, math, montecarlo, standard-deviation

I am performing a Monte Carlo operation on some Risks, the system works correctly but the standard deviation is completely off. When I simulate this value, the system is 100% accurate.

The input variables of the risk I have is the best case cost value, worst case cost value, most likely cost value, probability of risk occurring and the estimated value(Mean * probability).

My current implementation is this (In Java/Apex):

```
    public static Double calculateStandardDeviation(Decimal max, Decimal min, Decimal mostLikely, Decimal eV, Decimal prob){ 
        Double sum = 0,
        probability = prob;
        //uses standard SD calculation 
        sum += (min - eV) * (min - eV);
        sum += (max - eV) * (max - eV);
        sum += (mostLikely - eV) * (mostLikely - eV);
        //if the probability is not 100%, apply it to the calculation
        if(prob != 0){
            sum *= prob;
        }
        return Math.sqrt(sum);
    }
```

Further example:

If I have a Risk with the values:(Max = 300, Min = 100, mostLikely = 200, eV = 150, Prob = 75%). If I run this risk through my system, the standard deviation is 26.2. The value I know is correct is 94(although this needs to be /2 to function correctly). How would I get this value?

Any help on a more accurate equation would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: What distribution are you modeling here?  I was originally thinking you were describing a triangular distribution, but that only requires the min, max and mode to compute the standard deviation.

Comment: I am using triangular then applying the probability. I have applied this probability here as a test so please ignore the prob if you think it shouldn't be applied here.

Comment: Still not sure where you came up with the equation you did, but I have posted a response below which I hope helps.  If you have a different source for computing the standard deviation of a triangular distribution, please provide it; otherwise, I don't immediately see how your code is anything like that needed to compute stdev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a triangular distribution with `min`, `max`, and `mode`, the mean is given by:

```
mean = (min + max + mode) / 3
```

and the variance is given by [[source]](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/triangular_dist.html):

```
var = (min^2 + max^2 + mode^2 - min*max - min*mode - max*mode) / 18
```

Therefore the standard deviation is given by  [[source]](http://maths.nayland.school.nz/OHP_wordocs/Year_13/3.14_Distributions/12_Triangular_distribution.pdf):

```
stdev = sqrt(var)
      = sqrt( (min^2 + max^2 + mode^2 - min*max - min*mode - max*mode) / 18 )
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, I have subbed in the EV instead of mode as this brings me closer to the values im comparing against!